# Unconstrained Optimization Matrix Manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given a function to optimize,
$$ f(X) = \frac{1}{2}X^TQX+B^TX+C$$

where $Q$ is a constant matrix, $B$ is a constant vector and $C$ is a constant. 
To find the stationary point(s) we should find the gradient of this function when it is set to zero. i.e.) $\nabla f(X) = 0$

This is given as:
$$\nabla f(X) = QX + B = 0$$
First question: I dont see how this is obtained? Any step-by-step pointers or good videos would be welcome?
The stationary point is then given as:
$$X = -Q^{-1}B$$
This I can follow. Minus $B$ from both sides and then take the inverse of $Q$ on both sides. 
Next part I don't get. It is said that the Hessian matrix = $\nabla^{2}f(X) = Q$ and that $Q$ is inversable. I'm aware of what the Hessian matrix is but I don't get this step. Nor do I know what is the significance of $Q$ being inversable. Does that just mean that it is not singular.
Finally, I dont follow the remaining steps...
If Q is positive definite
$$ X^{*}=-Q^{-1}B $$
and therefore, $f(X)=C-\frac{1}{2}B^{T}Q^{-1}B$

If any can offer any help with this it would be very happily received.

Comment: You can obtain the gradient by directly calculating it using the sum-product definition of matrix multiplication. Or you can use the rules of differentiation on matrices here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities

Comment: If $Q$ is not invertible, then $Q^{-1}$ is not defined. In this problem $Q$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix, which means it's eigenvalues are all positive and hence $Q$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Also, in the first step, how does one actually apply the del operator here to find the gradient as being equal to $$\nabla f(X) = QX + B = 0$$